# How does the layout array work in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, layout

As I understand it, the \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory class is responsible for keeping an array of layout handles. According to [this tutorial](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html) there are 3 types of handles. You can add handles programatically by calling `$page->addPageLayoutHandles()` or `$page->addHandle()` (which is looks like addPageLayoutHandles just adds them through addHandle anyway).

Here is what I have

app/code/module/Social/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace module\Social\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{

    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param Context                                    $context           [description]
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory [description]
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory) 
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute() 
    {
        $page = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

        $page->addPageLayoutHandles(['one' => 'one', 'two' => 'two']);

        return $page;
    }
}
```

app/code/module/Social/view/frontend/layout/social_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="4columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="mycontainer">
            <block class="module\Social\Block\Social" name="social" template="socialmedia.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/module/Social/view/frontend/layout/social_index_index_one_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="mycontainer">
            <block class="module\Social\Block\Social" name="social" template="socialmediaone.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/module/Social/view/frontend/layout/social_index_index_two_two.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="mycontainer">
            <block class="module\Social\Block\Social" name="social" template="socialmediatwo.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image: Output]

Now, if I hit the page at `http://mylocal/social/index/index`, Magento calls my controller because I have it in the path for the action. When it hits that controller I am adding `social_index_index_one_one` and `social_index_index_two_two` to the array. Here are all of my questions.

- How does this array of handles work?
- Why is it that the last handle in the array is the template that gets output?
- What is the point in adding other template handles then?
- If I was to add sku or id handles what is the point of that?

The documentation on handles is pretty bad, and I can not find any explanation on the point of these handles in any detail.